# How to stop Visual Studio 2013 automatic reformatting

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

How do I stop the following from happening in VS2013?  It doesn't happen in VS2008 - possibly from VS2010 onwards.  I type

```
int GetCount() const { return count
```

And everything is OK.  When I type the ; it becomes

```
int GetCount() const {
    return count;
```

And when I type the }, it becomes

```
int GetCount() const {
    return count;
}
```

What I'd really, really want is

```
int GetCount() const { return count; }
```

If I don't type in the ; and go back and insert it, it behaves as I would like it to, except that I have to remember to go back and insert the ;

I have looked at Tools -> Options -> Text Editior -> C/C++.  I haven't tried all the options but from the descriptions, I can't figure out what would stop this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These options are in

> Text Editor >> C/C++ >> Formatting >> General

The one you want is

> Automatically format statement when I type a ;

[image]

The particular formatting settings that are being applied when you  press `;` are those set in Formatting >> New Lines.